# How do I enable NFC for my Phone

Tags: htc-desire-hd, nfc

There have been a lot hype about NFC lately, and I am eager to try it out, but unfortunately I dont think my HTC Desire HD supports NFC. Is there a way to enable NFC for HTC Desire HD ?

Answer (score 7):

Negative. The [HTC Desire HD](http://www.htc.com/www/product/desirehd/specification.html) does not have an NFC chip.

Comment: At this time there is no external accessory for android phones that provide NFC to phones lacking this capability and your phone does not have this capability, so no, you can't use NFC on your phone.